# thinkfan - startup command doesn't start

Tags: command-line, sudo, startup, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad and I usually use [thinkfan](http://thinkwiki.de/Thinkfan) to control the fan on my laptop. But this program doesn't start at the startup automatically, so I created a startup program with this command:

```
sudo  /etc/init.d/thinkfan start
```

That is the command in the guide to start thinkfan.

But this didn't work.
How can I fix?

Comment: This just starts the thinkfan service for the current session from my point of view, but doesnt implement a permanent service-start on boot

Comment: Does `sudo thinkfan -n` work (as per [this](http://thinkwiki.de/Thinkfan#Testbetrieb))?

Comment: the command works.